# What is controlling the layout of customer view orders?

Tags: commerce

On the page located at user/%user/orders/%commerce_order, I am having a hard time figuring out what .tpl.php is dictating its layout.

Namely, I have tried editing commerce_backoffice/theme/commerce-order--backoffice.tpl.php and clearing the cache, but I see no change.

I know very little about theming and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Also [this question](https://drupalcommerce.org/questions/3976/how-do-i-override-page-display-at-userorders) on drupalcommerce.org covers the same topic.